# JavaFX - Storing Data to corresponding button

Tags: java, javafx

Disclaimer: I'm completely new to JavaFX.

With that said, I'm making an Othello game, naturally I'll have an 8x8 boardgame.

I have enums for the state of each board square: empty, black, white.

For each board square, I have a button. I have it where I can change the color, keep track of turns, etc. My problem is, I feel as if I'm hacking things together for the below reason:

I do not know how to *properly* store a enum to it's related button. At first I figured I would just have a class that holds the button and an enum type (white, black, empty). However, when I use the GridPane, I can't add this object, but only the button in the object itself, thus losing the enum data. I could use a cheap work around and simply check the css style of a particular button, and forget about the enums all together. (For example if the color is white, I know white player has that particular square). This seems like the wrong way.

There must be some sort of collection or the likes in where I can do this the "JavaFX" way.

I'm open to questions if I'm not being clear/precise enough..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would Map<Button, MyEnum> buttonStatus = new HashMap<Button, MyEnum>(); do the work ?

Comment: This would, but later down the road I will be adding an AI using Monte Carlo algorithm. I want data that is easily copied and manipulated for memory efficiency of the tree. I am currently storing the data in a multi-array so I can track legal moves and token flips.

This, and I suppose I'm looking for the "JavaFX" way more so than just any solution. I do thank you for your reply, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple implementation is to store [userData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-) to a node:

```
button.setUserData(enumValue);
```

Retrieve userData from a node:

```
MyEnum enumValue = (MyEnum) button.getUserData();
```

---

Another way to handle it is to add custom state to your button via subclassing:

```
class Square extends Button {
    private ObjectProperty<SquareState> state = new SimpleObjectProperty(
        SquareState.EMPTY
    );

    public ObjectProperty<SquareState> stateProperty() {
        return state;
    }

    public SquareState getState() {
        return state.get();
    }

    public void setState(SquareState newState) {
        state.set(newState);
    }
}
```

---

For a more complicated mvc style approach where each item has a skin and an internal state you could review this [tic-tac-toe implementation](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5115901), as the management of the internal state of each piece can be similar in concept.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I was assuming ObjectProperty could do the trick for me, as I surfed for solutions but I wasn't sure how. I realized it was a wrapper and the likes but insofar as implementing in such a way where it was beneficial for me was questionable. I will use that solution, but I appreciate all the avenues given.

This is what I was looking for